# Is the supremum the same as maximum here? Is the maximum empty?

Tags: real-analysis

I have an example of a set

[image]

I decided to use $f(a) = a + (2a)^{-1} \implies f'=1 -2(2a)^{-2} = 1-1/a^2=0 \iff a=\frac{\pm1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Now I realize the critical values aren't even in the set, but taking $f(a)$ at those values anyways I get

$f(1/\sqrt{2}) =\sqrt{2}$

$f(-1/\sqrt{2}) =0$

Now evaluating through the end points, we get

$f(0.1) = 51/10$

$f(5) = 51/10$

So although the critical values don't belong to $\mathbb{Q}$, we do get that

sup(B) = 51/10

inf(B) = 0

max(B)=min(B) = empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all real $x$ in our interval, let $f(x)=x+(2x)^{-1}$.

You can see from the derivative that  as $x$ travels from $0.1$ to $5$, $f(x)$ decreases, then increases.

The supremum (**and** maximum) of the set $B$ is therefore, by your calculations, $51/10$.

The negative $x$ at which the derivative is $0$ is irrelevant. The positive $x$ at which $f'(x)=0$ is very relevant.

In our interval, the function, **if** interpreted as being defined for all reals in the interval, attains a minimum at $x=1/\sqrt{2}$. But this is regrettably not rational.

Since there are rationals arbitrarily close to $1/\sqrt{2}$, the set  $B$ has no minimum. But the infimum of $B$ **does** exist. It is obtained by evaluating $f(x)=x+(2x)^{-1}$ at $x=1/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I am a little confused. Why did we take the values of $1/\sqrt{2}$ in the end? It doesn't belong to $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: It does not belong to $\mathbb{Q}$, so $B$ does not have a minimum. But there are rationals arbitrarily close to $1/\sqrt{2}$, so by choosing suitable rationals $r$ we can make $f(r)$ arbitrarily close to $f(1/\sqrt{2})$, and therefore the infimum of $B$ is $f(1/\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: *But there are rationals arbitrarily close to $1/\sqrt{2}$*, I don't understand this part. What do you mean by getting close? We just find a rational number that is roughly $1/\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Yes. Imagine for example looking at the decimal expansion of $1/\sqrt{2}$. Truncate after $20$ places to get $r$. Then $f(r)$ is very close to $f(1/\sqrt{2})$. Continue, truncating after $100$ places. The elements of $B$ are always $\gt f(1/\sqrt{2})$, but we can find elements of $B$ as close to $f(1/\sqrt{2}$ as we wish. So the infimum of $B$ is $f(1/\sqrt{2})$.